# Apple iPad is not turning on and my home button is broken to force restart

Tags: ipad, hardware

Three days ago when I tried to use my iPad it did not turn on (black screen). I fixed it to the charger and nothing happened. After one day of trying I decided to search online. And yes, there is a very popular solution, intact a whole Apple page dedicated to how to fix it (https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201412)

*Holding the Sleep/Wake button along with the Home button for 10 seconds fixes this.*

However the thing is, my **home button** is broken. Even though I still tried, knowing its broken for the past few days it gave me the expected result which is - didn't turn on.

Tried fixing to the laptop/iTunes. Nothing happens.

**How can I fix this? Without the home button working**

*I do not have Apple care for this product as it is an old iPad (iPad 2)*

Comment: You can still have Apple fix an iPad if it doesn't have AppleCare...

Answer (score 1):

I found some software that might let you put your iPad into recovery mode: (Source: [Apple Support Communities thread])[1](http://jaxov.com/2010/05/recboot-iphone-recovery-mode/)

[RecBoot](http://jaxov.com/2010/05/recboot-iphone-recovery-mode/)

[TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/)